# Check if Model is empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing below query to fetch data to view however if `AccountMediaServerKey` table is empty. Model is throwing null exception error in view. Any idea how to check if model is null when NO data fetched from database

```
var MediaKey = (from p in db.AccountMediaServerKey
                where p.Tagger == USID && p.TagTo == USID
                select new MediaServerHomeModel
                {                                 
                    Stream=p.Stream,
                    Event = p.Event,
                    Status = p.Status

                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `if(Model!=null){ //do something on Model }` ?

Comment: it always through error if AccountMediaServerKey table is empty..I tried this option what you suggested

Comment: which specific line of code is throwing errror ? You need to include the relevant code in question.

Comment: In view I am checking if @Model.MediaKey.Stream is null or not but it always returns null value

Comment: What is your view strongly typed to ? How does that class structure looks like ? from your above comment, it looks like some class which has a `MediaKey` property.

Answer (score 1):

The method `FirstOrDefault` returns the first item in the collection or `NULL`. So if your table is empty, the variable `MediaKey` will have NULL value. If you are passing that to the view, make sure you do a null check before accessing any properties.

```
@model MediaServerHomeModel
<h1>Index</h1>
@if(Model!=null)
{
  <p>Model is not null</p>
  <!-- Access Model safely now -->
}
```

You have to do the same thing for other reference type properties to prevent null reference exception. For example if `Stream` property is a reference type, It is possible that it could be null. So it is safe to do a null check before using that as well.

```
@if(Model!=null && Model.Stream!=null)
{
  <p>Model.Stream is not null</p>
  <!-- Access Model.Stream safely now -->
}
```

Comment: I think the `?.` notation can be useful here as well if displaying the defaults is an option as in: `Model?.Status`. Your thoughts?

Comment: It is , if he OP is using the version of C# that supports this.

Comment: You make a valid point. I sometimes forget to consider older versions of the platform/language

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 ways 
first check your query if its null

```
if (MediaKey == null)
{
 //do some thing
}
```

Or you can check it before query like below :

without filtering:

```
if(db.AccountMediaServerKey.Any())
 {

 }
```

with filtering:

```
if(db.AccountMediaServerKey.Any(p=> p.Tagger == USID && p.TagTo == USID))
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply do

```
If(MediaKey==null) 
{ 
   //do something
}
```

Or if you want to instatiate a new object when null then you would do

```
var obj  = MediaKey ?? new MediaServerHomeModel();
```

The return obj to view